# Simplifying fractions with power-1 in the denominator

Tags: calculus

Simplify

\begin{align}&\color{white}=\frac{m(m^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}-2m^2(m^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{(m^2+1)^{-1}}\\\\
&= \frac{m(m^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}[(m^2+1)^1-2m]}{(m^2+1)^{-1}}\\\\
&= \frac{m(m^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}[m^2-2m+1]}{(m^2+1)^{-1}}\end{align}

My problem with simplifying this is mainly on how did I ended up with a quadratic equation in the brackets and unclear on how to apply indices law to remove the power of $-1$ from the denominator.

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Because you have a negative power, which is equivalent to 1/a, you can purge this by multiplying the entire equation by a (in this case, m^2 + 1).

Comment: Here's how to write part of your expression in MathJax. You can fill in the rest by following this example: \$\frac{m(m^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}}{(m^2+1)^{-1}}\$ formats to be $\frac{m(m^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}}{(m^2+1)^{-1}}$. \frac{top}{bottom} creates a fraction with "top" over "bottom" so \frac{1}{2} is one half.

Answer (score 1):

multiplying numerator and denominator by $$m^2+1$$ we get
$$m(m^2+1)^{3/2}-2m^2(m^2+1)^{1/2}$$ can you finish?